azure-spring-data-cosmos:3.14.0 not compatible with JDK17
I use Springboot 2.5.8 and azure-spring-data-cosmos:3.14.0. This was perfectly working with JDK11. But, when I tried upgrading JDK 1to 17, it started giving the below errors:
ava.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private final long java.util.UUID.mostSigBits accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.util" to unnamed module @15de0b3c
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:354)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.checkCanSetAccessible(Field.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.setAccessible(Field.java:172)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.makeAccessible(ReflectionUtils.java:791)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.doWith(AbstractMappingContext.java:520)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithFields(ReflectionUtils.java:714)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.doAddPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:401)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:365)
    at java.base/java.util.Collections$SingletonSet.forEach(Collections.java:4905)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.createAndRegisterProperty(AbstractMappingContext.java:568)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.doWith(AbstractMappingContext.java:526)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithFields(ReflectionUtils.java:714)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.doAddPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:401)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:365)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.getPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:258)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.getPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:201)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.getPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:87)
    at com.azure.spring.data.cosmos.core.convert.MappingCosmosConverter.read(MappingCosmosConverter.java:63)
    at com.azure.spring.data.cosmos.core.CosmosTemplate.toDomainObject(CosmosTemplate.java:963)
    at com.azure.spring.data.cosmos.core.CosmosTemplate.emitOnLoadEventAndConvertToDomainObject(CosmosTemplate.java:959)
    at com.azure.spring.data.cosmos.core.CosmosTemplate.lambda$runQuery$24(CosmosTemplate.java:840)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:106)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onNext(FluxOnErrorResume.java:79)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.drainLoop(FluxFlatMap.java:713)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.drain(FluxFlatMap.java:589)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onSubscribe(FluxFlatMap.java:956)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:201)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:83)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:8642)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(FluxFlatMap.java:427)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPublishOn$PublishOnSubscriber.runAsync(FluxPublishOn.java:440)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPublishOn$PublishOnSubscriber.run(FluxPublishOn.java:527)
    at reactor.core.scheduler.WorkerTask.call(WorkerTask.java:84)
    at reactor.core.scheduler.WorkerTask.call(WorkerTask.java:37)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
    Suppressed: java.lang.Exception: #block terminated with an error
        at reactor.core.publisher.BlockingSingleSubscriber.blockingGet(BlockingSingleSubscriber.java:100)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.block(Mono.java:1742)
        at com.azure.spring.data.cosmos.core.CosmosTemplate.runQuery(CosmosTemplate.java:842)
        at com.azure.spring.data.cosmos.repository.support.StringBasedCosmosQuery.execute(StringBasedCosmosQuery.java:72)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:159)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:138)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215)
        at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy149.findAll(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
        at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215)
        at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy149.findAll(Unknown Source)

How to resolve this issue. As per the the spring-data-cosmos documentation, it is expected to work JDK8+
I checked if upgrading azure-spring-data-cosmos is an option for us. But, we don't want to upgrade spring boot at the moment.

check answers of this similar kind of thread if it helps you.
